# Не всегда приходит хэш транзакции web3 metamask

Tags: javascript, web3.js

есть метод, через который человек оплачивает, так скажем услугу.
суть проблемы в том, что человек оплачивает, потом должен прийти хэш, который я должен отправить на бэкенд, чтобы учетная запись человека, к примеру, активировалась.

```
const register = (contract, price) =>
    contract.methods
      ._register(Number(settings.ref_id || 0))
      .send({ value: window.web3.utils.toWei(String(price)) })
      .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
        sendTx(hash, settings.id, token).then((res) => {
          toast(JSON.stringify(t("toast:SUCCESS")), { type: "info" });
          setBuyLoading(false);
        });
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        setBuyLoading(false);
        toast(err.message, { type: "error" });
      });

после ".send" проходит оплата, и иногда не приходит тот самый хэш.

вот здесь отправляется хэш, который я должен получить после отплаты человека, и отправить на бэкенд

export const sendTx = async (transactionHash, userId, token) => {
  console.log(transactionHash, userId);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.smart-profit.info/save-tx`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ user_id: userId, tx_hash: transactionHash }),
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch {
    sendTx(transactionHash, userId, token);
  }
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вот исправил. Помогите пожалуйста, если можете.